# Find the first number whose factorial is divisible by x?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, factorial

I am new to assembly coding if any silly mistakes please correct me.....

> Given a number x, your task is to find first natural number i whose factorial is divisible by x.
>
> - The number x will be stored in register %rax using the mov instruction.
> - The final result should be stored in register %rdi.
> - Assume x is chosen such that overflow does not occur.

My attempt:

```
factorial:  

    pushq %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp 
    cmpq $1, %rdi   
    je if           
    jmp else

if:
                 
    movq $1, %rax
    jmp factend

else:
             
    pushq %rdi      
    subq $1,%rdi    

    call factorial  
    popq %rdi       
    mulq %rdi      

    jmp factend      

factend:

    movq %rbp, %rsp
    popq %rbp
    ret
```

Comment: That looks like an inefficient recursive factorial that might work.  Note that your assignment wants you to use a backwards calling convention where the arg is in RAX and the return value is in RDI.  It would also be easier to add a divisibility check to a loop that started upwards from `1`, not downwards from `x`.  Brute force that way is probably just as efficient as factorizing `x` into its prime factors for small `x`.  Either way, you don't want to separately compute a factorials for every div, that would be pointlessly slow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's work on the question:

> Given a number x, your task is to find first natural number i whose factorial is divisible by x.

That is, find `n` such that `n! % x == 0`.

If you split `n!` and `x` into their prime factors (e.g. like "60 = 2*2*3*5") you know the remainder will be zero when all the prime factors in `x` are also prime factors in `n!`; which means that `n` must be equal to or larger than the largest prime factor of `x`.

For a worst case, if `x` is a prime number (only one prime factor) then `n` will have to be equal to `x`. For example, if `x` is 61, then `n` will be 61. This is important because `n!` becomes large quickly and will overflow (e.g. `61!` won't fit in 64 bits).

Fortunately; if `n` is larger than 2; `n!` is the same as `(n-1)! * n`; and `((n-1)! * n) % x` is the same as `((n-1)! % x) * n) % x`.

In other words; to make it work (to avoid overflows) you can do something like this (without every calculating `n!` itself):

```
do {
  i = i + 1;
  remainder = remainder * i;
  remainder = remainder % x;
while(remainder != 0);
```

Now...

> Assume x is chosen such that overflow does not occur.

What does that actually mean?

If the person asking for the code assumed you'd be using the algorithm I've described; then it would probably mean that `x` will be less than the square root of 1 << 64); and therefore you will have overflows if you use a "more likely to overflow algorithm" (any algorithm that does calculate the value of `n!`) so you must use my algorithm (or find a better algorithm).

In any case; recursion is bad and unnecessary.